# How to get statistical records (transactions) from all servers using BAPI function "SWNC_STATREC_READ_INSTANCE"?

Tags: sap-basis, bapi, sapjco3

We are using "***SWNC_STATREC_READ_INSTANCE***" BAPI function to get statistical records by user for particular time interval. This is working fine if there is only one application server, but with multiple application servers, it is not fetching records if user performs transactions in different application server.

Please suggest any other way to get records/transactions performed by particular user for particular interval of time from all application servers.

We are executing this function through ***JCO*** and did not find the parameter to specify the server name in this BAPI.

Comment: The list of application servers can be obtained via the function `TH_SERVER_LIST` and you may call `SWNC_STATREC_READ_INSTANCE` once per server, you pass the server name through the parameter `target_instance`.

Comment: @Sandra Rossi, our SAP system is ECC, not seeing this the param "TARGET_INSTANCE" in  param list of this BAPI? any setting to make it appear or this param is available only for HANA systems?

Comment: The parameter is unrelated to HANA database. I can see it's available in old ABAP-based systems (7.40 SP 10 and backported to 7.31 SP 15, dixit [Note 2088824](https://me.sap.com/notes/2088824/E)). I guess your only solution is to contact SAP people at your company. NB: `SWNC_STATREC_READ_INSTANCE` is not BAPI, it's just RFC-enabled.

Comment: @Sandra Rossi, it worked. Thanks. Please make your comment as an answer.

Comment: I don't know what is your exact solution, could you post one instead please, making things clear if possible? Thanks!

Comment: @SandraRossi, apologies for confusion. The very first comment of yours ( using the TARGET_INSTANCE param) to get the txn logs from multiple application servers is worked. Please make the same as an answer, so I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of application servers can be obtained via the function `TH_SERVER_LIST` and you may call `SWNC_STATREC_READ_INSTANCE` once per server, you pass the server name through the parameter `target_instance`.

The parameter `target_instance` is available in old ABAP-based systems (7.40 SP 10 and backported to 7.31 SP 15, dixit [Note 2088824](https://me.sap.com/notes/2088824/E)). If you don't have this parameter, I guess your only solution is to contact SAP people at your company.

NB: `SWNC_STATREC_READ_INSTANCE` is not BAPI, it's just RFC-enabled.